# Issues doing require_once in a Laravel folder

Tags: php, laravel, require, autoload

I have a situation where I've been forced to use something that SHOULD be a composer package in my Laravel project, instead, as just part of my project files (the composer package as far as I can tell contains bugs that I cannot resolve and I'm using a folder of similar php files my colleague provided to me)

I'll try to give as much context as I can:

I've installed all the files into a folder at this directory: `\app\Channels\V1\Helpers\MarketplaceWebService\`. The files are similar to [this project](https://github.com/coopTilleuls/amazon-mws-orders), but different

In order to get the classes in the above folder loaded, I've added a line to my composer.json file:

```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "app/Channels/V1/Helpers/MarketplaceWebService"
        ]
    },
```

That last line in the classmap array - I used that to load my classes into my project, so I can now require them via `use MarketplaceWebService_Client;` at the top of any of my normal laravel files

Now for a lot of cases, this works -- I can initiate classes and they pull from the correct place.

However, any time I use one of the MarketplaceWebService that have a relative `require_once`, it fails

I have ANOTHER composer package by the same guy, tilluels, called `amazon-mws-orders`, and it looks based on the error message I'm receiving that these relative `require_once` calls are for some strange reason being made relative to that package, rather than relative to the location of the file I'm in.

So for example, if a file has `require_once ('Interface.php');`, and `Interface.php` is in the same folder as that file, it works just fine, BUT if a file has `require_once ('../Model.php')`, I get this lovely message:

```
500 - {"message":"MarketplaceWebService_Client::main(): 
    Failed opening required '../Model.php' 
   (include_path='/home/devchannelapi/laravel/vendor/tilleuls/amazon-mws-orders/src:.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear')",exception":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",

 "file":"/home/devchannelapi/laravel/app/Channels/V1/Helpers/MarketplaceWebService/Model/SubmitFeedResponse.php","line":22
```

And I set some breakpoints in Xdebug and it is, in fact, line 22 on `/Model/SubmitFeedResponse.php` where it says `require_once('../Model.php')`, and the `Model.php` class is indeed one directory above that file, so you'd expect the require_once statement to work. And in fact, if I make a copy of `Model.php` and put it into the `/Model` folder, and change the require statement to `require_once('Model.php')`, it actually DOES work! But whenever I leave the relative requires, it gives me an error message like above, as if it's looking for relative requires in `/home/devchannelapi/laravel/vendor/tilleuls/amazon-mws-orders/src`

Now I've already done `composer dump-autoload`, I don't know enough about Laravel class loading to understand why else this might be happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replace all relative imports with `__DIR__` imports

eg `require_once('../Model.php);` becomes `require_once(__DIR__ . '/../Model.php);`

Was a bit of a pain to edit every file in the folder, but Sublime Text was a great help!